# How to add a SID to a folder permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, acl

How can I add a specific SID to a folder's access control list? I'd like to give it permission to read.

I'd like to have the final ACL look like this:

[image: SID I want to add]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How to add a SID to a folder permissions**
>
> How to add a specific SID to a folder's permission like the image and
> give it read permission.
>
> [image]

You can do this with **`ICACLS`** from Windows command prompt, but be sure to plug in the exact SID though and folder path in those parts of the below command examples.

**Two Examples Below**

```
 ICACLS "C:\Path\Folder" /grant "*S-1-15-2-1485859843:(R,RX)"
 ICACLS "C:\Path\Folder" /grant:r "*S-1-15-2-1485859843:(R,RX)"
```

---

**Source and Further Reading:** `ICACLS /?` from a command line

```
ICACLS name /save aclfile [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    store the the acls for the all matching names into aclfile for
    later use with /restore.

ICACLS directory [/substitute SidOld SidNew [...]] /restore aclfile
                 [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    applies the stored acls to files in directory.

ICACLS name /setowner user [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    changes the owner of all matching names.

ICACLS name /findsid Sid [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    finds all matching names that contain an ACL
    explicitly mentioning Sid.

ICACLS name /verify [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    finds all files whose ACL is not in canonical for or whose
    lengths are inconsistent with ACE counts.

ICACLS name /reset [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    replaces acls with default inherited acls for all matching files

ICACLS name [/grant[:r] Sid:perm[...]]
       [/deny Sid:perm [...]]
       [/remove[:g|:d]] Sid[...]] [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
       [/setintegritylevel Level:policy[...]]

    /grant[:r] Sid:perm grants the specified user access rights. With :r,
        the permissions replace any previouly granted explicit permissions.
        Without :r, the permissions are added to any previously granted
        explicit permissions.

    /deny Sid:perm explicitly denies the specified user access rights.
        An explicit deny ACE is added for the stated permissions and
        the same permissions in any explicit grant are removed.

    /remove[:[g|d]] Sid removes all occurrences of Sid in the acl. With
        :g, it removes all occurrences of granted rights to that Sid. With
        :d, it removes all occurrences of denied rights to that Sid.

    /setintegritylevel [(CI)(OI)]Level explicitly adds an integrity
        ACE to all matching files.  The level is to be specified as one
        of:
            L[ow]
            M[edium]
            H[igh]
        Inheritance options for the integrity ACE may precede the level
        and are applied only to directories.

    /inheritance:e|d|r
        e - enables inheritance
        d - disables inheritance and copy the ACEs
        r - remove all inherited ACEs


Note:
    Sids may be in either numerical or friendly name form. If a numerical
    form is given, affix a * to the start of the SID.

    /T indicates that this operation is performed on all matching
        files/directories below the directories specified in the name.

    /C indicates that this operation will continue on all file errors.
        Error messages will still be displayed.

    /L indicates that this operation is performed on a symbolic link
       itself versus its target.

    /Q indicates that icacls should supress success messages.

    ICACLS preserves the canonical ordering of ACE entries:
            Explicit denials
            Explicit grants
            Inherited denials
            Inherited grants

    perm is a permission mask and can be specified in one of two forms:
        a sequence of simple rights:
                F - full access
                M - modify access
                RX - read and execute access
                R - read-only access
                W - write-only access
        a comma-separated list in parenthesis of specific rights:
                D - delete
                RC - read control
                WDAC - write DAC
                WO - write owner
                S - synchronize
                AS - access system security
                MA - maximum allowed
                GR - generic read
                GW - generic write
                GE - generic execute
                GA - generic all
                RD - read data/list directory
                WD - write data/add file
                AD - append data/add subdirectory
                REA - read extended attributes
                WEA - write extended attributes
                X - execute/traverse
                DC - delete child
                RA - read attributes
                WA - write attributes
        inheritance rights may precede either form and are applied
        only to directories:
                (OI) - object inherit
                (CI) - container inherit
                (IO) - inherit only
                (NP) - don't propagate inherit

Examples:

        icacls c:\windows\* /save AclFile /T
        - Will save the ACLs for all files under c:\windows
          and its subdirectories to AclFile.

        icacls c:\windows\ /restore AclFile
        - Will restore the Acls for every file within
          AclFile that exists in c:\windows and its subdirectories

        icacls file /grant Administrator:(D,WDAC)
        - Will grant the user Administrator Delete and Write DAC
          permissions to file

        icacls file /grant *S-1-1-0:(D,WDAC)
        - Will grant the user defined by sid S-1-1-0 Delete and
          Write DAC permissions to file
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with GPO?

Comment: Trying to apply this horrible capability SID back to my Server 2019 machines with a domain GPO: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_server_2019/2019-12-12/finding/V-93025

Comment: @vomit-it-chunky-mess-style We applied Registry Permissions via GPO without realizing the "Capability SID" (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-the-heck-account-unknowns-1-15-3-1024/65852c0e-d185-4eef-abfb-967263519cc0?page=2) was necessary. Now we have to add the SID back to the registry permissions, hopefully via GPO but there's no way in the GUI to add it back. I think I've found a way by cracking security templates open in notepad however.

Comment: @duct_tape_coder.... Yes, I have had to change a template like that before as well to get broken GPO to stop showing per some old Internet Maintenance GPO setting. I always like having backups before changes to critical systems for quick reversion if possible. Messing with the registry can cause problem so use caution!! Good luck, I hope you work it all out!

Comment: @vomit-it-chunky-mess-style For reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/1147969/how-can-i-add-a-capability-sid-to-gpo-registry-permissions/1147970#1147970

Comment: @duct_tape_coder It just now clicked what you were talking about "Capability SID", nice find! I dropped a comment on your SF "Q" post to what seems to be a related post they wrote up about this too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/sids-not-resolve-into-friendly-names